# How do I assign a number to a raffle ticket index

Tags: microsoft-excel

Here is the sample data I expect to receive. I want add the Mbr (Member) No to Column I based on the number of tickets purchased.

[image: Sample Raffle Data]

Comment: Use the edit button to add information to your question. Comments aren't for adding info to your question. What have you tried?

Comment: My bad, found the edit button and corrected my question. I've been researching and had a look at a couple of macro's but was getting a compile error with one I found. I'm hoping there is a formula but will use a macro is that's the only way.

Comment: We are neither a recommendation service nor are we a code writing service. You'll need to show us what you've tried and what the outcome was for a start.

Comment: in column G (or elsewhere if you prefere) you want to keep a running total of the tickets sold.  You can then do a LOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH based on the running total to determine which ticket belongs to who.